# Can a Lucas Carmichael number also be a Smith number?

Tags: nt.number-theory, recreational-mathematics

I was wondering if a Smith number can be a Lucas Carmichael number.

Is there a proof that there is no such number?

If there is such a number, can you tell me it and how you got it?

I have written a brute force program and so far I have found no such number between 1 and 1,000,000.

Thanks, Remy

Comment: Please define both kinds of numbers in your question.

Comment: I guess https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_number and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas-Carmichael_number

Comment: I suppose one could argue that this question is rather unmotivated, since it takes two "random" categories of numbers, very loosely related, and asks for their intersection. Of all possible categories of numbers, do you have any reason to choose these two particular ones?

Comment: Upvoted because I want to see the answer, but I agree, it is very unmotivated.

Comment: “Smith numbers were named by Albert Wilansky ... He noticed the property in the phone number (493-7775) of his brother-in-law Harold Smith.” Mind boggles.

Comment: @Wojowu it seems that results on Smith numbers that are also in some other category (palindromic, squares, cubes, Fibonacci,...) are particularly appreciated among the cult followers, as the wide bibliography testifies. The C2-symmetric Smith numbers are also investigated, like 666609999.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are all numbers below $10^9$ that are both Smith and Lucas-Carmichael:

8164079, 8421335, 21408695, 30071327, 47324639, 77350559, 103727519, 121538879, 134151479, 202767551, 239875559, 287432495, 306871487, 466861199, 560974259, 566019167, 574342145, 592557119, 594633599, 602758079, 677913599, 832477799

UPDATE. These numbers now form http://oeis.org/A277580

Comment: Hey – there's my phone number!

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Now you know its purpose.

Comment: Thank You, if I may, how did you get these numbers? Is there some formula, algebra, or did you brute force check? Thank you again

Comment: @RemyRouyer: Just a kind of brute force.